# mozroots command fails with Unsupported hash error

Tags: 12.04, mono, certificates

I am using the following set of command on a new install of 12.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get install -qq python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:v-kukol/mono-testing
sudo apt-get update -qq > /dev/null
sudo apt-get install -qq mono-complete mono-gmcs > /dev/null
mozroots --import --sync
```

The `mozroots` command fails, though, with the following error message.

```
Mozilla Roots Importer - version 3.0.12.0
Download and import trusted root certificates from Mozilla's MXR.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.
Downloading from 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...

Importing certificates into user store...

Error: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3
at Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS1.HashNameFromOid (System.String oid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS1.CreateFromOid (System.String oid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.get_Hash () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection.IndexOf (Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection.Contains (Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Tools.MozRoots.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Tools.MozRoots.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I did not have this issue when I used Mono 2.10.8.1 (default version for 12.04). However, I need some of the newer features of Mono for my application now.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanking to [poupou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220643/poupou), we have already an answer:

> This was fixed recently. The easiest way to get the fix is to update to Mono 3.2.x. An alternative is using an older Mono (e.g. 2.10) to download the certificates.

<sup>Source: [mozroots command fails with Unsupported hash error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18191183/2353900)</sup>